# CMake inlucde project file without folder prefix

Tags: c++, cmake

My project structure is the following:

```
-Engine
 |-Shaders
 | '-shader.glsl
 |-source
 | |-Math
 | |'- matrix.hpp
 | | - vector.hpp
 | '-Lua
 | |'-lua_state.hpp
 '-CMakeLists.txt
```

I am using CMake as build system and my question is :

How can I include for example `matrix.hpp` into `lua_state.hpp` without using the prefix for folder path ? i mean instead to use in lua_state.hpp `#include "../Math/matrix.hpp"` , just included like this -> `#include "matrix.hpp"` , there is any way to do this with CMake ?

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the include path for compiler (-I option)
To include it for all targets ([docs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/include_directories.html))

```
include_directories(source/Math)
```

or use target properties ([docs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/target_include_directories.html))

```
target_include_directories(yourAppOrLibTargetName PRIVATE source/Math)
```

Comment: good answer, but it would be even better if you replace `PRIVATE` by `PUBLIC`, since you include `matrix.hpp` in a header.

Answer (score 0):

Add the directory to the include path by calling the [`include_directories` command](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/include_directories.html).

You'll also need to make sure the header files are declared as dependencies of the library or executable you're creating, either using [`add_library`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_library.html) or [`add_executable`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_executable.html). I can't quite tell what you'll need based on the files you listed.